# YouCompleteMe post install error : cannot import name _compare_digest

Tags: python, ubuntu, vim, conda, miniconda

I am trying to install YouCompleteMe plugin on a source compiled Vim instance. I have a server without sudo privileges, hence I had to compile new Vim (7.4+) in order to make most plugins work. Also, I have installed miniconda and thus refer to the python in miniconda for all installations.

While following all steps how to install YouCompleteMe plugin (via Vundle or even manually), I faced this issue : "Cannot find module urllib3". So I installed urllib3 via pip, and then the error changed to "cannot import name _compare_digest". Point to note that conda virtualenv (I have just made the miniconda bin to $PATH) cannot start and it still shows "Cannot find module urllib3" even after installing it explicitly.

Is there something wrong with the way I installed vim? I had been extra careful to point to miniconda python wherever it's needed. How do I mitigate this issue and get the plugin running again?

Answer (score 0):

When I had trouble with dependencies I had to run

`git submodule update --init --recursive`

in the YouCompleteMe directory to get the dependencies installed.

Also make sure you have taken all of the other steps here:

https://valloric.github.io/YouCompleteMe/#full-installation-guide

One of those steps may fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

**In Short**

Just go to `ycmd` submodule inside `YouCompleteMe` folder, or to be exact in the `YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd` and the run the git submodule command bellow.

`git submodule update --init --recursive`

**Explantion**

I've got the same issue like yours, 
It was caused by the submodule of `YouCompleteMe` not being cloned properly.

This command should be able to solve the problem.

`git submodule update --init --recursive`

But unfortunately the problem still persist, the problem at which `urllib3 not found` , and instlling the library using pip won't be able to solve this issue.

The problem actually located in `ycmd` submodule at which needing `urllib3` or to be more precise the `requests` submodule of `ycmd` needed it.

After some experimenting, the main problem was the git submodule command unable to properly clone the submodule, at which rasing an error about module not found.

Hope, this can be a help for you :)